# Zend Framework 2.0 Interface not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework2

#### Short version

Where does the Client class look for the `DispatchableInterface` interface?

```
class Client implements Libraries\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface
```

---

I'm trying to add the ZF2 libraries to a CodeIgniter installation. The whole Zend folder sits in:

```
 /Users/stef/Sites/site_name/application/libraries/
```

In my CI controller I have

```
public function run()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('Zend');
    $CI->load->library('Zend/Http/Client');
    $client = new Client($url);

    //Do stuff
}
```

When I access the run() method I get a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Interface `'Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface'` not found in /Users/stef/Sites/site_name/application/libraries/Zend/Http/Client.php on line 27

In libraries/Zend.php (a file I added, not part of the ZF) I have

```
function __construct($class = NULL)
{
    // include path for Zend Framework
    // alter it accordingly if you have put the 'Zend' folder elsewhere
    ini_set('include_path',ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPPATH . 'libraries/Zend/');
    }
```

It doesn't seem to matter what I set the include_path to be, even when I put bogus values the fatal error stays the same. So it seems that the loading of the interface `DispatchableInterface` doesn't make use of the include_path.

How can I get Client.php to "find" the interface, which it tries to do so here:

```
class Client implements Libraries\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Least difficult solution is probably:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/Users/stef/Sites/site_name/application/libraries/');
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
$loader->register();
```

Then skip the `CI->load` part. And just use `new Zend\Http\Client`. Also make sure that the dispatchable interface is in `/Users/stef/Sites/site_name/application/libraries/Zend/Stdlib/DispatchableInterface.php`

**Update:**
I noticed just now:

```
class Client implements Libraries\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface
```

What class is this? Is it Zend's class? I guess it's some class of yours. And you're adding wrongly namespaced interface. IMO it should be `\Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface`

Comment: This still gives an error Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\Http\Libraries\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface' not found in /Users/stef/Sites/site_name/application/libraries/Zend/Http/Client.php. The 'Zend\Http\Libraries\Stdlib\' path is obviously wrong but I have no idea where it gets it from.